# Subdomain redirection with htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect to subdomain different folder. Like this, demos.mysite.com to mysite.com/demos

I'm try with this but it doesnt redirect.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^emre\.emreozdmr\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/emre/
RewriteRule (.*) /emre/$1
```

What can I do? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^emre\.(emreozdmr\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!emre/).*)$ /emre/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: I change like this but it doesn't working
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^emre\.(emreozdmr\.com)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/emre/
RewriteRule (.*) http://%1/emre/$1 [L,R]

Comment: Where is this .htaccess located and what URL did you use for testing. Also are there more rules in this .htaccess?

Comment: .htaccess file in my root dirrectory (httpdocs). I have 2 rule. The second one just redirect www.emreozdmr.com to emreozdmr.com with 301. It works but this rule doesnt work. I'm testing with  emre.emreozdmr.com and emre.emreozdmr.com/index.php

Comment: Place this rule before your other rule. Also what is `DocumentRoot` of `emre.emreozdmr.com`?

Comment: Actually I removed second rule(301 rule) and I tested with one rule. Index.php Index.html etc.. My documentroot. I'm using hostgator hosting I'm not sure does it change anything.

Comment: Can you create a file called `info.php` with this code `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and then open `http://subdomain.domain.com/info.php` to check what is its `DOCUMENT_ROOT` value.

Comment: I added info.php but when I try to reach it with emre.emreozdmr.com/info.php 404 Not Found.. I remove .htaccess file and try to reach like this http://emreozdmr.com/emre/info.php and (_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] /home/emreozdmr.com/httpdocs)

Comment: ok try updated rule now in `/home/emreozdmr.com/httpdocs/.htaccess`

Comment: I feel myself idiot but I already put .htaccess file in the this path.. /home/emreozdmr.com/httpdocs/.htaccess

Comment: ok can you try loading `emreozdmr.com/emre/info.php` and `emreozdmr.com/info.php` and let me know how it goes.

Comment: I just add your answers rule. I removed all of my rules. Now I have just one rule in my .htaccess file. I try emreozdmr.com/emre/info.php it's ok. emreozdmr.com/info.php 404 Not found. emre.emreozdmr.com/info.php - 404, emre.emreozdmr.com/emre/info.php - 404 Not found

Comment: I suspect `DocumentRoot` of `emre.emreozdmr.com` is something else. Because I am getting 404 for both `http://emre.emreozdmr.com/emre/info.php` and `http://emre.emreozdmr.com/info.php`

Comment: I suspect too. I open the case about this problem my hosting provider company. I'm waiting answers. I think there is a different problem. When I catch to something I will write there. Really thank you for your help!

Comment: I think if you can get `VirtualHost` entry of `emre.emreozdmr.com` that should be good enough.